# Toulmin model of argumentation

Tags: discourse-analysis, discourse

I am studying the [Toulmin model of argumentation](http://writing2.richmond.edu/writing/wweb/toulmin.html) to use it in the analysis of Presidential debates. I have tried to read many sources, but I couldn't really find an exact answer about which part should come first in using this theory: a claim or data (evidence). It says that the Toulmin model is based on the development of syllogism. His theory is based on deductive reasoning, which goes from general to the specific. This means it starts from a claim first. However, there are some studies that still use this theory even though its argument starts with data first.  I appreciate any answer :)

Comment: Hi @angie. Interesting question! I edited it to make it easier to read. Do feel free to undo any changes you think were not appropriate.

Comment: If you have to diverge a bit from doctrinaire Toulmin model, that is OK and even to be encouraged in the field, where your paper is ignored unless it proposes some extension or modification to a particular theory/framework.